# Specifying a custom record delimiter for sqoop export to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqoop, impala

I have a table (created in Impala) that I am trying to export to MySQL using direct mode:

`CREATE TABLE export_table (
field1 string,
field2 string[...]
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\u0002
STORED AS TEXTFILE`

I'm doing it this way because the fields have multi-line data.

I'm able to my mysqlimport do the right things with the `--fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\002'` options, however, Sqoop still things that \n is the right record separator character.

I've tried using `--input-lines-terminated-by '\002'` without any success.

Does anyone have any insight?